# Elasticsearch: Sort by _script using php client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

Is there a way to sort by _script from php client? I haven't found a way to achieve that, but I did manage to do it from cURL.

If I do the query from cURL I can do the following and it works.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/name/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query":{"bool":{"must":{"multi_match":{"query":"hello","type":"best_fields","fields":["title","description"],"operator":"and"}}}},
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "source": "doc[\u0027language\u0027].value == \u0027en\u0027 ? 1 : 0"
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

But if I do it from PHP the sort parameter is added to the query string and not to the post body. And I couldn't make it work.

First I tried:

```
$params = [
    'index' => self::INDEX_NAME,
    'from' => $offset,
    'size' => $pageSize,
    'body' => [],
];

$params['sort'] = ['_script' => ["script" => ["source" => "doc['language'].value == 'en' ? 1 : 0"], "type" => "number", "order" => "desc"]]

$params['body']['query']['bool']['must']['multi_match'] = [
    'query' => $query,
    'type' => 'best_fields',
    'fields' => [
        'title',
        'description',
        'subject',
    ],
    'operator' => 'and',
];


/**
 * @var ElasticResponse
 */
$response = $this->elasticClient->search($params);

$arrayResponse = $response->asArray();
```

And the result was: `No mapping found for [Array] in order to sort on.`

Then I tried to send the sort param encoded:

```
$params['sort'] = json_encode(['_script' => ["script" => ["source" => "doc['language'].value == 'en' ? 1 : 0"], "type" => "number", "order" => "desc"]]);
```

and I end up with the param in the query string and it doesn't work.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index/_search?sort=%7B%22_script%22%3A%7B%22script%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%22doc%5B%27language%27%5D.value+%3D%3D+%27en%27+%3F+1+%3A+0%22%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%22number%22%2C%22order%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%7D
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `sort` should be inside the `body`.

```php
$params['body']['sort'] = [
    "_script" => [
        "script" => ["source" => "doc['language'].value == 'en' ? 1 : 0"], 
        "type" => "number",
        "order" => "desc"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paulo, but no, that was a mistake on my question. I'll fix it right away

Comment: Maybe share the more of the script then ?
If you look at [this search](https://cs.github.com/?scopeName=All+repos&scope=&q=path%3A*.php+_script+painless+sort)  you will find some example btw.

Comment: You are right Paulo, sorry, I've added the full call to Elastic from PHP

Comment: Also I don't have access to Github Code search :(

Comment: Post updated 

Comment: It really works, I don't know how many iterations I did... Thanks a lot!